# PostgresQL ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am doing an SQL `JOIN...ON` in which the column of the other table to join on is an array to a set of rows, and therefore encounter this error. Specifically, I'm doing the `JOIN` on the tables.

TABLE: location

```
+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| session_id |  gpstime   |   lat   | lon      |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+
|         49 | 1458203595 | 39.7449 | -8.8052  |
|         59 | 1458203601 | 39.7438 | -8.8057  |
|         95 | 1458203602 | 39.7438 | -8.8056  |
|         49 | 1458203602 | 39.7438 | -8.8057  |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+
```

TABLE: trips

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------+
| session_ids | lat_start | lat_end | lon_start | lon_end | travel_mode |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------+
| {49}        | 39.7449   | 41.1782 | -8.8053   | -8.5946 | car         |
| {59,60}     | 41.1551   | 41.1542 | -8.6294   | -8.6247 | foot        |
| {94,95}     | 41.1545   | 40.7636 | -8.6273   | -8.1729 | bike        |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

Here's the query I used:

```
SELECT gpstime, lat, lon,  travel_mode
FROM location
INNER JOIN trips
    ON session_id = session_ids
WHERE (lat BETWEEN SYMMETRIC lat_start AND lat_end) 
   AND (lon BETWEEN SYMMETRIC lon_start AND lon_end);
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
LINE 4:  ON session_id = session_ids
```

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=` comparator can only compare two values of the same type. But here you are trying to compare an integer value with an array. So the value `1` cannot equal a value that look like `[1,2]`.

You can use the `= ANY(...)` comparator which checks if the left value is part of the right array:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e3aefc65ec5b44734522ac8f5e2d67de)

```
ON session_id = ANY(session_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

S-Man is correct, although you can also use the ANY function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375533/postgresql-how-to-join-tables-on-array-column).

For more information on the differences between using IN and ANY/ALL, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql).